# How can I output this in JSON format by overriding?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I'm trying to console log this using overiding, but I'm getting error. Code works fine when I remove `JSON.stringify(arguments[0])`, But I need it in JSON format.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var t_log= console.log;

    console.log = function(){
        arguments[0] = JSON.stringify(arguments[0])+" sessionID " + req.sessionID + " requestID=" + req.id +" timestamp"+ new Date();
        t_log.apply(console, arguments);

    }
    console.log("call");

    next();

});
```

Comment: What is `arguments[0]` to begin with? What is `arguments.length`? What error are you getting?

Comment: @Paul I'm getting infinite '\' in console.

Answer (score -1):

Converting a generic object to true JSON:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(my_generic_object))
```